# How to hide the navbar on page print (bootstrap 5)?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to print the page body, but the vertical "navbar" still shows up and covers a part of it.

This is the code i am using to hide the navbar on print:

```
@@media print and (min-width: 800px){
            #print {
                display: none;
            }
        }
```

This is the navbar loaded on _Layout.cshtml, as a partial view:

```
<partial name="_MenuSidebarVerticalPartial"  id="print" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the class [`.d-print-none`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/#display-in-print).

Comment: use class for this example